# Grant permission to user on database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, user-permissions

Users are created with `dbcreator` and `public` role. They can create and delete their own databases.

How do I give them the ability to grant permission to their database to other users?  Currently they can only see public and guest object.

Comment: I think you should add db_owner

Comment: the user already has dbo role for his database?  I don't want to grant him sysadmin role, but it seem to be the only way I know of, right now, to give him the ability to grant others access to his database.

Comment: grant with grant option

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make someone a `sysadmin`. The minimum required permissions are described on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql).

> In SQL Server, requires `ALTER ANY LOGIN` permission on the server or
>   membership in the `securityadmin` fixed server role.

These permissions still give a user a lot of power. They are able to delete other sysadmin logins.

Perhaps [partial contained databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases) can be a solution for you.

A database user in a regular database needs to be mapped to a login on server level. Managing these server level logins requires a lot of permissions.
Database users within a partially contained database can exists without a login. These users can only login to that specific database. No server level permissions are required to manage these users.